# How can I show that the number of permutations of [n] so that 1, ... , k are in separate cycles is n!/k!?

Tags: combinatorics

So I honestly don't even know where to start. Does it mean that a number k within the permutations is what we are looking for or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Every permutation can be decomposed into disjoint cycles. For example $(1,2,3) (4,5)$ can be used to denote the permutation that maps $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 1$ and $4 \to 5 \to 4$. The question asks how many permutations of $n$ objects have $1,2,\cdots,k$ all in different cycles.

**Hint**: The easiest way is via induction. Check that it works for $k$ objects. Now create a $1$-to-$(n+1)$ correspondence between such permutations for $n$ objects and such permutations for $n+1$ objects. You must prove both directions of the correspondence.

Answer (score 1):

Take a random permutation in $S_n$, decompose it as a product of disjoint cycles, and erase all numbers larger than $k$. Show that the resulting permutation is a random permutation in $S_k$. Since the probability that a random permutation in $S_k$ satisfies your condition is $1/k!$ (only the identity permutation), the result follows.